# New compile error in Xcode 14.3: "Mixing declarations and code is incompatible with standards before C99"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode14.3

I am currently working on an iOS project and I'm utilizing the XCDYouTubeKit library (https://github.com/iOSDev-Auction/XCDYouTubeKit) to handle YouTube video playback. The library was initially compiled successfully in Xcode 14.2. However, upon upgrading to Xcode 14.3, I encountered an error stating "Mixing declarations and code is incompatible with standards before C99" during the compilation process.

I have thoroughly researched the issue but haven't found any specific solutions or workarounds related to this library and Xcode version combination. I suspect that this error might be due to some changes in the compiler settings or language standards in Xcode 14.3.

Already checked below solutions:
1st mention in the thread https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729290
by adding detail WARNING_CFLAGS = -Wno-declaration-after-statement under User-Defined in build setting

2nd by setting C Language Dialect to C99.
both not working.

Comment: You're using a bad library. Switch to https://github.com/alexeichhorn/YouTubeKit

Comment: Maybe update the WARNING_CFLAGS settings, with the found flag "-Wno-declaration-after-statement". In the XCDYouTubeKit/XCDYouTubeKit.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file, around line 604.  Good Luck.